# Python function continues running after return statement?

Tags: python

The following function ends with the TypeError: Unsupported operand types float and NoneType.
How is it possible for a base case to fire a `return None` and the program continue with `factorial() = None`. At least this is how I perceive it.

```
def factorial(i):
  if i < 0:
    return None # Why does the program not stop here?...
  if i == 0:
    return 1
  return i * factorial(i-1) #factorial(i-1) returns None after i < 0?

print(factorial(3.01))
```

Comment: The base case stops running, but the case before it keeps running and tries to do the multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because `return i * factorial(i-1)` is getting called in your function, and `factorial(i-1)` is evaluating to `None`.

The reason it's evaluating to `None` is the input value you gave - `3.01` - this will result in the following:

```
factorial(3.01) # returns 3.01 * factorial(3.01-1)
factorial(2.01) # returns 2.01 * factorial(2.01-1)
factorial(1.01) # returns 1.01 * factorial(1.01-1)
factorial(0.01) # returns 0.01 * factorial(0.01-1)
factorial(-0.99) # returns None (because i < 0)
```

Therefore, the line `0.01 * None` is run, which results in your error.

Comment: Which value of `i` would invoke that condition?

Answer (score 1):

The last recursive call in your function is

```
return 0.01 * factorial(-0.99)
```

`factorial(-0.99)` invokes the `if i < 0:` case, so it returns `None`. Then the above code tries to multiply `0.01 * None`, which causes the error you got.

Your definition of `factorial` is only valid for non-negative integers.